# facebook graph api oauthtoken error code 1 errors

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am not sure where on the developers page I can post issues but will try here anyway. I am now seeing multiple errors for requests that have been working for months and not sure what the exact issue is. When polling the graph api for the pages endpoint, the following error is returned. I have seen this error before but usually only occurs occasionally at times. It is now occurring for multiple applications that are running with different access tokens:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/112231398821172/
 feed?  limit=150&access_token=xxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=read_stream 


{
  "error": {
  "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 1
 }
}
```

Is anyone aware of any issues that are not currently listed on graph api status page that could be related. Does anyone have any idea as to why this would occur so frequently? I know rate limiting has a different error return code 403

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that's because you're asking for "read_stream". This permission is no longer granted unless you're building an app on a platform that doesn't currently have a native Facebook app. In order to get this approved you'd have to develop your own new OS for something (like a printer) and then make a FB app for that OS.

[Source Quoted Bellow. Scroll down to "read_stream" section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2)

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.